# Angular 7 3D model viewer

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js, webgl, 3d-model

Is there a way to make a 3D model viewer in Angular 7. I have been using the   [model-viewer, web component](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/model-viewer), so far in JS and it is working great. How can I achieve the same functionality and viewer in Angular 7 application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [Three js](https://threejs.org/) ? it's very powerful